# How to run Mac file on Linux?

Tags: 15.10, macosx, photography

Is there any way to run a Mac file on Ubuntu 15.10? I want to run Aurora HDR on my Ubuntu, but I can't find any way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can! There is a compatibility layer for OS X ,called - Darling( https://www.darlinghq.org/ ). You can open a Mac file on a Linux distro with this software,good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

There no way to run MacOS files in ubuntu, however if it's not graphical depending app you should be able to install it into Virtual Machine and run through there.